# Algorithm for finding the best traders

Tags: data-mining, dataset

I have a data of 700,000 transactions of forex traders which use various tools for investments. For beginners i want to find the association patterns between following metrics

- performance / ROI
- activity..
- Instruments (e.g. Eur/USd, Eur/JPY etc.)
- win/loss ratios
- Margin used.

Then after that i want to find out what kind of above mentioned attributes contribute to the greatest win/loss ratios. Once the association patterns are made, i can look for the patterns with win/loss ratio and find out what associations are positively affecting this ratio.

I am currently running apriori but it's taking forever to output results. I wanted to know what are some other ways i can solve this problem?